# How to have two different color histograms?

Tags: r, image-processing

I have already produced the two histograms representing the circumference of trees in public parks in Montreal vs. Paris. Throughout my analysis, I have used a color code: dark blue for Montreal and light blue for Paris. I would like to use that color code for my histograms but can't find how... Best I could come up with is a mix of dark and light blue in each histogram. But it is not what I'm looking for...

I want the left histogram in dark blue and the right one in light blue, according to cities (`arbres$Ville`). How could I do that?

```
city=unique(arbres$Ville)
par(mfrow=c(1,2),cex.main=1.3)
for(i in 1:2){
  hist(arbres$circon[arbres$Ville==city[i]],col=c("darkblue","light blue"), 
       xlab="Circonférence des arbres (cm)", ylab="Fréquence",main=NULL,
       xlim=range(arbres$circon),cex.lab=1.1)
  title(paste("Distribution de la circonférence des arbres\nà",city[i]))
}
```

Comment: set up a colour vector `colvec <- c("darkblue","light blue")` and use `col=colvec[i]` in your `hist()` call.

Comment: So simple!!! I have search for hours! Thanks!

Comment: feel free to post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Here are the final code:

colvec=c("darkblue","lightblue")
city=unique(arbres$Ville)
par(mfrow=c(1,2),cex.main=1.3)
for(i in 1:2){
  hist(arbres$circon[arbres$Ville==city[i]],col=colvec[i], 
       xlab="Circonférence des arbres (cm)",             
       ylab="Fréquence",main=NULL,
       xlim=range(arbres$circon),cex.lab=1.1)
  title(paste("Distribution de la circonférence des arbres\nà",city[i]))
}

Comment: You're allowed (and encouraged) to post that as an answer to your own question.